# What is it that makes methods such as Select, Join, Where a Linq-to-Object's standard query operators and not...?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

1) Internally, what is it that makes methods such `Select`, `Join`, `Where` etc ( besides the fact that query expressions get translated by compiler into these method calls )  a Linq-to-Object's *standard query operators* and not just regular methods that happen to operate on sequences of data?

Namelly, all the functionality offered by those operators could also be implemented in regular methods, but we don't call those regular methods *standard query operators*?!

2) Same question for Linq-to-XML methods – thus, what makes them *query operators* and not just regular methods that operate on XML data?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well they *are* "just regular (well, extension) methods" but they're also defined in the LINQ [Standard Query Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397896.aspx) page on MSDN:

> The standard query operators are the methods that form the Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) pattern. Most of these methods operate on sequences, where a sequence is an object whose type implements the IEnumerable interface or the IQueryable interface. The standard query operators provide query capabilities including filtering, projection, aggregation, sorting and more.

One interesting question is whether [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) should count as a standard query operator, given that it was introduced in .NET 4...

Comment: I thought that perhaps compiler somehow treats operators differently ( besides the fact that query expressions get translated into operator calls ), but from your reply it seems only difference between Linq operators and regular methods ( that offer the same functionality ) is that the former are defined inside Linq namespace?

Comment: @user702769: No, there's nothing special here - the compiler couldn't care less about the namespace. These are *extension* methods, but that's all that's unusual about them... and you can write extension methods which are nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: uhm, I have this nagging feeling that I'm still missing something obvious. I apologize for being repetitive - so only thing that makes Linq operators different from regular methods ( with same functionality ) is that compiler is somehow informed which methods are Linq operators and is thus "willing" to translate query expressions into those operator calls?

Comment: @user702769: Ah, query expressions are a different thing - and the C# compiler doesn't know about *all* LINQ operators as part of query expressions... only some. (More in VB than in C#.) See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx for more details.

Comment: From your link: "The whole thing is pattern based. If you have an API which provides some or all of the operators used by the pattern, in an appropriate way, you can use query expressions with it." Could you elaborate on what you mean by "pattern based" and why do only some operators fit into that pattern and thus can be used by query expression?

Comment: @user702769: Basically it's just done by name: query expressions can only contain certain contextual keywords, which get converted as per the blog post. If you write methods which match the names the C# compiler is looking for, they'll be used. Read the C# spec for more details on the pattern.

Comment: What's more, the query expressions are completely duck typed in that if there is a Where method in scope for the current type (or extending the current type) that returns an IEnumerable<T>, you can use the query expression over it. This is what enables things like query expressions over IObservable (Reactive Extensions), LINQ to Amazon [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2006/06/26/Introducing-Linq-to-Amazon.aspx), etc.